# Disable Ubuntu 22.04 automatic aws kernel updates

Tags: upgrade, kernel, 22.04, automatic

I have a ubuntu 22.04 server running on AWS. A while ago there was an automatic kernel update which caused the server to crash and it was a nightmare since it was headless (aws).

Since then I manually reverted the kernel back to  `Linux 5.4.0-1018-aws` using the instructions here (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-downgrade-the-kernel-on-ubuntu-20-04-to-the-5-4-lts-version/26459) and it has never updated the kernel since (I don't know if I did something, I don't see anything in `50unattended-upgrades` in the blacklisted section). That's exactly what I wanted, I don't want it to upgrade the kernel but it is updating everything else (using unattended upgrades). That's the perfect scenario.

Recently I manually updated the kernel to `Linux 6.2.0-1009-aws` and everything is working great. Now I want to ensure that it doesn't upgrade the kernel anymore, however it does continue to upgrade all the other packages. I'm concerned that since I'm now on the latest aws kernel version it will also automatically update the aws kernel. My question is how do I check if the aws kernel is going to be updated and more importantly how do I set it to so that the aws kernel is never updated automatically unless I manually update it myself (but I do want the rest of packages to be updated)?

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not a good advice to hold updates on any package (since updates are just security fixes), you can use `apt-mark hold` to avoid updates on any package.

More info [here](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/apt-mark.8.html#:%7E:text=hold%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20hold%20is%20used%20to%20mark%20a%20package%20as%20held%20back%2C%20which%20will%20prevent%20the%20package%20from%20being%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20automatically%20installed%2C%20upgraded%20or%20removed.)
And an example [here](https://www.tecmint.com/disable-lock-blacklist-package-updates-ubuntu-debian-apt/#:%7E:text=The%20command%20apt%2Dmark%20will,being%20installed%2C%20upgraded%20or%20removed.)

Comment: Some "updates", especially kernel, when not done properly can cause the system to crash as what happened in my case. The "security" update caused it to crash and it was nearly impossible to recover from it on a headless system. Could you elaborate on which specific package does one need to place a hold to avoid a kernel update?